# Pairwise distance between a set of Matrices in Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, matrix-multiplication

I want to calculate pairwise distance between a set of `Tensor` (e.g 4 Tensor). Each matrix is 2D Tensor. I don't know how to do this in vectorize format. I wrote following *sudo-code* to determine what I need:

```
E.shape => [4,30,30]

  sum = 0
  for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        res = calculate_distance(E[i],E[j]) # E[i] is one the 30*30 Tensor
        sum = sum + reduce_sum(res)
```

Here is my last try:

```
x_ = tf.expand_dims(E, 0)
y_ = tf.expand_dims(E, 1)
s = x_ - y_
P = tf.reduce_sum(tf.norm(s, axis=[-2, -1]))
```

This code works But I don't know how do this in a Batch. For instance when `E.shape` is `[BATCH_SIZE * 4 * 30 * 30]` my code doesn't work and Out Of Memory will happen. How can I do this efficiently?

**Edit**: After a day, I find a solution. it's not perfect but works:

```
res = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.map_fn(lambda y: tf.map_fn(lambda z: tf.norm(z - x), x), x), E)
    res = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(res))
```

Comment: Define what exact formula you want to compute and for what matrix shape. Is it this one - https://math.stackexchange.com/q/507742/238620 ?

Comment: @Maxim yes exactly. I wanna calculate pairwise distance between a set of matrix but I dont know how to do that.

Comment: As far as I can see it's defined between 2D matrices, not 3D.

Comment: @Maxim thanks for your reply, edit my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution with `expand_dims` should be okay if your batch size is not too large. However, given that your original pseudo code loops over `range(4)`, you should probably expand axes 1 and 2, instead of 0 and 1.

You can check the shape of the tensors to ensure that you're specifying the correct axes. For example,

```py
batch_size = 8
E_np = np.random.rand(batch_size, 4, 30, 30)
E = K.variable(E_np)  # shape=(8, 4, 30, 30)

x_ = K.expand_dims(E, 1)
y_ = K.expand_dims(E, 2)
s = x_ - y_  # shape=(8, 4, 4, 30, 30)

distances = tf.norm(s, axis=[-2, -1])  # shape=(8, 4, 4)
P = K.sum(distances, axis=[-2, -1])  # shape=(8,)
```

Now `P` will be the sum of pairwise distances between the 4 matrices for each of the 8 samples.

---

You can also verify that the values in `P` is the same as what would be computed in your pseudo code:

```py
answer = []
for batch_idx in range(batch_size):
    s = 0
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            a = E_np[batch_idx, i]
            b = E_np[batch_idx, j]
            s += np.sqrt(np.trace(np.dot(a - b, (a - b).T)))
    answer.append(s)

print(answer)
[149.45960605637578, 147.2815068236368, 144.97487402393705, 146.04866735065312, 144.25537059201062, 148.9300986019226, 146.61229889228133, 149.34259789169045]

print(K.eval(P).tolist())
[149.4595947265625, 147.281494140625, 144.97488403320312, 146.04867553710938, 144.25537109375, 148.9300994873047, 146.6123046875, 149.34259033203125]
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer, my batch_size is around 512-1024 and OutOfMemory will happen in GCS even for a large model server type.

Comment: @Amir Which GPU are you using? I executed the exact same code in this answer with a 1024 batch size, and it only takes 274MiB on GPU.

Comment: Did you changed the axis in `expand_dims` to 1 and 2?

Comment: I didnt notice about axis. let me try it :)

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow allows to compute the Frobenius norm via [`tf.norm`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/norm) function. In case of 2D matrices, it's equivalent to `1-norm`.

The following solution isn't vectorized and assumes that the first dimension in `E` is known statically:

```py
E = tf.random_normal(shape=[5, 3, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
F = tf.split(E, E.shape[0])
total = tf.reduce_sum([tf.norm(tensor=(lhs-rhs), ord=1, axis=(-2, -1)) for lhs in F for rhs in F])
```

**Update:**

An optimized vectorized version of the same code:

```py
E = tf.random_normal(shape=[1024, 4, 30, 30], dtype=tf.float32)
lhs = tf.expand_dims(E, axis=1)
rhs = tf.expand_dims(E, axis=2)
total = tf.reduce_sum(tf.norm(tensor=(lhs - rhs), ord=1, axis=(-2, -1)))
```

Memory concerns: upon evaluating this code,
 [`tf.contrib.memory_stats.MaxBytesInUse()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/memory_stats/MaxBytesInUse) reports that the peak memory consumption is `73729792 = 74Mb`, which indicates relatively moderate overhead (the raw `lhs-rhs` tensor is `59Mb`). Your OOM is most likely caused by the duplication of `BATCH_SIZE` dimension when you compute `s = x_ - y_`, because your batch size is much larger than the number of matrices (1024 vs 4).